# Add 4th column when first 3 columns are identical

Tags: python, unix, awk

I have file like this in which some of the lines are identical in first 3 columns and different values in 4th column.i want to sum all the values in the 4th column if first 3 columns are identical:

```
chr1 241783  286397   52
chr1 241783  286397   53
chr1 241783  286397   53
chr2 10500  25700   57
chr2 10500  25700   59
chr2 10500  25700   59
```

I want the output file like this:

```
chr1 241783  286397 158
chr2 10500  25700   175
```

I can print out the single identical value from the file using `awk` which I saw in one of the post by `awk '!array[$1,$2,$3]++'` .but I want to sum of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ awk '{a[$1FS$2FS$3]+=$4}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file
chr2 10500 25700 175
chr1 241783 286397 158
```

Comment: great thank you..i will accept the answer once the time completes @sudo_O